# Calculate a square root of a number in XSL

Tags: xml, function, xslt, math, sqrt

I have attempted several iterations of calculating a square root of a number in XSL/XML but can't get it working.  This is my latest attempt.  I am getting an error "Named template 'sqrt' does not exist in the stylesheet."  This is the last bit that I need to write for this stylesheet and then I can turn my project in.  -TIA

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-
 microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:inr="http://mycompany.com/mynamespace">
<xsl:import href="sqrt.xsl" />

<xsl:template match="HorizontalLine | HorizontalCircle | HorizontalSpiral">
<xsl:if test="Start[@pointType = 'POB']">
    SqRt:
      <xsl:call-template name="sqrt">
        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="100"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using? And what exactly is in the `sqrt.xsl` document?

Comment: http://exslt.org/math/functions/sqrt/math.sqrt.html

Comment: The EXSLT math.sqrt stylesheet contains a template called math:sqrt, not sqrt. Namespaces matter!

Comment: I attempted the math:sqrt and this did not work either.  As far as the contents of the sqrt.xsl, I do not know.  I followed the instructions given by the site.  I believe there is a comment that includes the link to the stylesheet.

Comment: when I used math:sqrt, I received an error stating the named template '(http;//exslt.org/math)sqrt' does not exist in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

The error message says that "named template 'sqrt' doesn't exist". We would expect to find it in `sqrt.xsl`, but you haven't shown us `sqrt.xsl`, so we can infer (a) that it's not there, and (b) that you probably don't understand how import works, otherwise you would have understood the message and shown us the code.

For an example of how to calculate square roots in XSLT 1.0, see http://exslt.org/math/functions/sqrt/math.sqrt.template.xsl

Two other comments:

(a) there is no XSLT version 1.1. There was a draft of 1.1 (round about 2001) but it was abandoned and never got beyond draft status.

(b) you say: "This is the last bit that I need to write for this stylesheet and then I can turn my project in". (i) This information is irrelevant to your question, and (ii) it reflects your inexperience, since an experienced programmer knows that you should never expect the bug you are currently working on to be the last one.

Comment: thank you for pointing out my inadequacies with XML.  I have never made the claim I was proficient in the language and I hope your comments make you feel better than me.

The 1.1 comes from the base document that I used as a template.  As you pointed out, my expertise is NOT XML.  I do not know what the implications are of 1.1 vs 1.0 in functionality.

When I attempt to place the
    <xsl:template name="math:sqrt">

Comment: I get an error stating the stylesheet is malformed.

Comment: Perhaps you failed to declare the math namespace prefix.

Comment: @MichaelMadrid you shouldn't take things so personally. Posting on a site like StackOverflow exposes your code to expert scrutiny, which is an excellent way of climbing up the learning curve. It should make you feel good that you have formulated a question that has enabled you to learn something.

Comment: LOL.  Agreed.  Very frustrated at this point.  I know vb, vbs, and .NET, but am lost in XML.  Thanks for the redirect.

Comment: So this is my namespace:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" 
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
        xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" 
        xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
        xmlns:inr="http://mycompany.com/mynamespace" 
        xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math" extension-element-
        prefixes="math">
    <xsl:include href="../format.xsl"/>
 <xsl:import href="sqrt.xsl" />
    <xsl:param name="xslRootDirectory" select="inr:xslRootDirectory"/>`

Comment: Please edit your question to add the full code of your stylesheet (abbreviated to the minimum needed to demonstrate the problem), including any included/imported modules. Don't put reams of code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:inr="http://mycompany.com/mynamespace" xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math">
<xsl:import href="sqrt.xsl" />
<xsl:include href="../format.xsl"/>
<xsl:param name="xslRootDirectory" select="inr:xslRootDirectory"/>
<!-- List Coordinates with Station Report -->
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="gridOut" select="inr:SetGridOut(number(InRoads/@outputGridScaleFactor))" />
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{$xslRootDirectory}/_Themes/engineer/theme.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<!-- Element Point Data -->
<xsl:template match="HorizontalLine | HorizontalCircle | HorizontalSpiral">
    <xsl:variable name="startStation" select="Start/station/@internalStation"/>
    <xsl:variable name="endStation" select="End/station/@internalStation"/>
    <!-- This section is to force the PC to PI information -->
        <tr>
            <xsl:variable name="varElementNumber" select="@elementNumber - 1"/>
            <!-- Element DIST Section -->
            <xsl:variable name="varX1" select="PI/@easting"/>
            <xsl:variable name="varY1" select="PI/@northing"/>
            <xsl:variable name="varX2" select="Start/@easting"/>
            <xsl:variable name="varY2" select="Start/@northing"/>
            <td class="sidepad" align="center">
            varElementNumber: <xsl:value-of select = "$varElementNumber"/><br/>
            varX1: <xsl:value-of select = "$varX1"/><br/>
            varY1: <xsl:value-of select = "$varY1"/><br/>
            varX2: <xsl:value-of select = "$varX2"/><br/>
            varY2: <xsl:value-of select = "$varY2"/><br/>
            Distance: <xsl:value-of select = "($varX2 - $varX1) * ($varX2 - $varX1) + ($varY2 - $varY1) * ($varY2 - $varY1)"/><br/>
            SqRt:   
                <xsl:call-template name="math:sqrt">
                    <xsl:with-param name="number" select="25"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </td>
            <!-- End Station -->
        </tr>
</xsl:template>
```